# Select one record when all records mapped to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables `Temp (IdentityId, Value)` and `Temp2 (IdentityId, ReferrenceId, Value)`.

I need to map these two tables and get one record from second table, which is mapped all record from first table to second table.

```
Create Table #Temp
(Id int,  Value int)

Insert into #Temp Values(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,2),(5,2),(6,3)


Create Table #Temp2
(
   Id2 int,
   Table1Id  int,
   OutPutValue int
)

Insert into #Temp2 Values(1,1,100),(2,2,100),(3,3,100),
                     (7,1,200),(8,2,200),
                     (4,1,300),(5,2,300),(6,3,300),
                     (9,1,400),
                     (10,2,500),
                     (11,4,600),(12,5,600),
                     (13,1,700),(14,2,700),(15,3,700)
```

These are my tables:

[image]
                        [image]

E.g.:

```
Select * From #Temp A
Inner Join #Temp2 B On A.Id=B.Table1Id 
Where A.Value=1
```

[image]

See the tecords in image that I have selected. 1st table single record is mapped to all three records on second table. So I need output like this

[image]

100,300,700 -> this values are mapped to all records of 1st table

Sorry, if you don't understand my question, please ask me.

Comment: is it mysql or sql server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Row_number partioning we can get

```
    ;WITH CTE as (Select *,
ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by OUTPUTVALUE order by id)rn 
From #Temp A
    Inner Join #Temp2 B On A.Id=B.Table1Id 
    Where A.Value=1)

    SELECT OUTPUTVALUE FROM cte where rn >= 3
```

Comment: You forgot the `;` at the end of your query ;)

Comment: it is giving exact output what the questionnaire has asked..any suggestions ??

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is about (probably a relational division query but it's not clear.) I only commended for the lack of query terminator in your code - and misplacing it at the start instead of the end of the query.

Comment: No actually it has been COMMON TABLE SYNTAX ;WITH like that it follows in MICROSOFT SQL Server

Comment: I know. The issue is that SQL-Server does not require a statement terminator. For now (because this behaviour is going to be deprecated and then terminators will be required.) For the moment it only requires that when a statement is a CTE and so starts with `WITH`, that the previous statement has been properly terminated. Adding a `;` before your `WITH`s solves this issue of other developers being sloppy and not properly terminating their statements. But you should at least add a `;` at the end of yours. It's kind of ironic when you don't, don't you think?

Answer (score -1):

You could do it like this, though this might not give you the desired results if have NULL values and may not be best depending on the size of your tables.

```
WITH AllAssigned AS
(
    SELECT
        OutputValue
        , (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT value) FROM #temp) AS TotalDistinctValues
        , COUNT(DISTINCT Table1Id) AS TotalAssignedValues

    FROM
        #temp2

    GROUP BY
        OutputValue
)

SELECT
    *

FROM    
    AllAssigned

WHERE
    AllAssigned.TotalDistinctValues = AllAssigned.TotalAssignedValues
```